# What protocol are we using for streaming, live if the request is an HTTP request that use TCP? How is UDP implemented?

Tags: http, web, networking, tcp, udp

I am currently studying the transport layer of the TCP/IP model, in particular of the protocols that are used, TCP and UDP. The thing I don't understand is if we use the browser through a URL to request a resource from a web server for example playing a live stream so through an HTTP request, in this case, the protocol that is used is TCP instead of UDP, right? But on the other hand in the cisco course from which I am studying as well as the school books also states that the UDP protocol is used for Live Streaming, Multiplayer games, VOIP.

In this case which of the two protocols are we using? My doubt lies precisely in the fact that if the request that is made is a web request through a URL and therefore an HTTP request, how is UDP implemented since HTTP uses TCP?

The thing that is not clear to me is how UDP is implemented when we, through URL (so an HTTP request which is of the TCP type), request a resource from a web server. If the resource in question is "watch a live stream on Twitch", how does the UDP protocol implemented since we are already using a "logical connection" established through TCP and we are already using reliable communication?

Comment: There are many transport protocols other than TCP and UDP. The transport protocol used is the one the application developer chose to use, and there can even be more than one used in an application.

Comment: `My doubt lies precisely in the fact that if the request that is made is a web request through a URL and therefore an HTTP request` __Iff__ the application uses HTTP requests. All these cases (Live Streaming, Multiplayer games, VOIP) can use other protocols.

Comment: HTTP isn't the only application protcol in the world.

Answer (score 2):

UDP is a protocol which does not care about reliable data transmission, i.e. packets can be lost, duplicated, reordered etc. TCP instead cares about **reliability**, which comes with added overhead and also comes with potential **latency** issues if packets got lost and need to be resend.

Based on this UDP is used when latency is a concern but reliability is not. This is the case for **real-time** media, like VoIP audio and video telephony. Too much latency in this use case is not acceptable for such bidirectional communication. Thus here are media codecs used which can deal with packet loss, i.e. latency is favored and non-reliability as a side effect is dealt with.

In streaming video (**non-real-time**) like on youtube latency is not that much of concern though. More important here is efficient use of bandwidth which means efficient media codecs with high compression rates. The more efficient a codec is the less it can handle loss of data. Thus reliability of the connection is a concern here and TCP is more suitable.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the thing that is not clear to me is how UDP is implemented when we, through URL (so an HTTP request which is of the TCP type), request a resource from a web server. If the resource in question is "watch a live stream on Twitch", how does the UDP protocol implemented since we are already using a "logical connection" established through TCP and we are already using reliable communication?  My Apologies for my bad English...

Comment: @L'uccellinochevola It isn't. HTTP works over TCP. You said that yourself. *Ergo* it doesn't work over UDP. But that doesn't mean that UDP can never be used, either by other higher-level protocols or directly.

Comment: @L'uccellinochevola: Real time media using UDP is in the browser handled by WebRTC. It is fairly complex protocol but in essence it will exchange descriptions of the UDP endpoints and codecs to be used over HTTP.